# Apache Mesos configured failed on OS X Yosemite

Tags: mesos

I am following the doc (http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) and trying to install Mesos on my mac. When I try to configure it, it gives me the error:

> checking python extra linking flags... -u _PyMac_Error Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
>   checking consistency of all components of python development environment... no
>   configure: error: in `/Users/syang/Desktop/git/mesos/build':
>   configure: error:
>     Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
>     installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
>     via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
>     Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
>     ============================================================================
>      ERROR!
>      You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
>      for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
>     ============================================================================

I use Python 2.7.8 and I am trying to install Mesos 0.23.0. I did some search, it looks like after installing command tools using xcode, the linking problem should get handled. However, it doesn't look like that to me. Is there anyone who has similar experience and can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually going to use Mesos python module? If not, just run `./configure` with `--disable-python`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of running Mesos on local machine is to use https://github.com/bobrik/mesos-compose (Docker) or https://github.com/mesosphere/playa-mesos (Vagrant)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bit different when build it in OSX. You could use "brew install mesos" to install it directly. https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula/mesos.rb also show how to build mesos in osx.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have resolved this issue but for future reference I would like to suggest the below steps based on this blog http://gwikis.blogspot.com/2015/08/building-mesos-0230-on-os-x-yosemite.html

`$ cd mesos-0.x./build/
$ PYTHON=/usr/bin/python ../configure`

Moreover in case that you receive any errors like `libapr-1 is required for mesos to build.` or `libsubversion-1 is required for mesos to build.` then you could do the following, assuming that apr and subversion libs are installed with brew.

`$ PYTHON=/usr/bin/python ../configure -with-svn=/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.8.13/ -with-apr=/usr/local/Cellar/apr/1.5.2/libexec/`

To verify why the Python path is not correct and the compile fails in the first place please go once through the blogpost.